# Вывод одинаковых значений из двух массивов

Tags: javascript, массивы

Написать метод, который определяет, какие элементы присутствуют в двух экземплярах в каждом из массивов (= в двух и более, причем в каждом).
На вход подаются два массива.
На выходе массив с необходимыми совпадениями.
Пример:
[7, 17, 1, 9, 1, 17, 56, 56, 23], [56, 17, 17, 1, 23, 34, 23, 1, 8, 1]
На выходе [1, 17]

Сам код, который не работает как задумывалось. Возможно где-то опечатка. Да и код сам слишком огромный, но в голову другое пока не пришло)

```
let massive1 = [7, 17, 1, 9, 1, 17, 56, 56, 23];
let massive2 = [56, 17, 17, 1, 23, 34, 23, 1, 8, 1];

function firstFilter(mass) {
let ks=[];
for(let value of mass){
ks[value] = (ks[value]||0)+1;
}
let arr =[];
for(let i in mass) {
if ( ks[ mass[i] ] > 1 ) {
arr.push(mass[i]);
ks[ mass[i] ] = 0;
}
}
return arr;
}

function secondFilter(mass1, mass2) {

let updateMass1 = firstFilter(mass1);
let updateMass2 = firstFilter(mass2);

let i = updateMass1.length, j = updateMass2.length, resultMass = [];
while (i > 0 && j > 0) {
i--;
j--;
if (updateMass1[i] > updateMass2[j]) j++;
else if (updateMass1[i] < updateMass2[j]) i++;
else resultMass.push(updateMass1[i]);
}
return resultMass;
}

console.log (secondFilter(massive1, massive2));
```

Comment: скопировал ваш код в консоль, запустил, на выходе массив `[1,17]` что не так? или вы выложили код, который дает правильный результат только на этом наборе данных?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно что-то такое сделать..

UPD: Если добавить проверку `if(res.includes(cm[i])) continue;` на больших выборках с множеством одинаковых значений, время выполнения сократится ~ в двое

```js
let m1 = [7, 17, 1, 9, 1, 17, 56, 56, 23,1,];
let m2 = [56, 17, 17, 1, 23, 34, 23, 1, 8, 1];


function find(mm1, mm2){
  let res = [];
  let cm = mm1.slice(0); // клонируем массив
  for(let i = 0; i < cm.length; i++){
    if(res.includes(cm[i])) continue; // если текущий уже записан в результат, переходим к следующему
    delete cm[i] // удаляем текущий элемент
    if (cm.includes(mm1[i]) && mm2.includes(mm1[i])) { // проверяем наличие удалённого элемента, если есть и присутствует во втором массиве
        let cm2 = mm2.slice(0); // клонируем второй массив
        delete cm2[cm2.indexOf(mm1[i])] // ищем индекс и удаляем элемент
        if(cm2.includes(mm1[i])) res.push(mm1[i]) // если элемент после удаления встречается в массиве, добавляем 
    }
  }
  return res
}

console.log(find(m1, m2))

// added

function _find (m1, m2, n = 0) {
  let o = m1.reduce((a,b)=>{ a[b] ? a[b]++ : a[b] = 1; return a },{});
  let o2 =m2.reduce((a,b)=>{ a[b] ? a[b]++ : a[b] = 1; return a },{});
  for(let k in o) if(o[k] < n || o2[k] < n || !o2[k]) delete o[k];
  return Object.keys(o).map(Number)
}
console.log( _find(m1, m2, 1), _find(m1, m2, 2), _find(m1, m2, 3))

function __find (m1, m2, n = 0) {
  let obj = [...m1,...m2].reduce((o,k)=>{ o[k] ? o[k]++ : o[k] = 1; return o },{});
  return Object.keys(obj).filter( k => obj[k] / 2 >= n ).map(Number)
}
console.log( __find(m1, m2, 2))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: На здоровье! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr1 = [7, 17, 1, 9, 1, 17, 56, 56, 23];
let arr2 = [56, 17, 17, 1, 23, 34, 23, 1, 8, 1];

function findAndAddSameElems(arr1, arr2) {
  const resultArr = []
  for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
      if (arr1[i] === arr2[j]) {
        resultArr.push(arr1[i])
      }
    }
  }
  const resultUnicArr = Array.from(new Set(resultArr))
  console.log(resultUnicArr)
}
findAndAddSameElems(arr1, arr2)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]